# How to set the value of ControlTemplate in UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin, uwp, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

I working on Xamarin project and made custom renderer for my custom control in UWP project. I found how to set the ControlTemplate by using xml code.

XML Way:

```
var tb = new TextBox(); // or what I do in Xamarin var tb = Control;

var ct = (Controls.ControlTemplate)XamlReader.Load(@"
<ControlTemplate TargetType=""TextBox"" xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' xmlns:x='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'>
    <Grid>
       ....
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>");

tb.Template = ct;
```

But how I can do the same in code?

```
var tb = new TextBox(); // or what I do in Xamarin var tb = Control;


var ct = new ControlTemplate();
ct.TargetType = typeof(TextBox);

var grid = new Grid();
ct.VisualTree = grid // This is how it was done in wpf but there is no such option in UWP

tb.Template = ct;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported in UWP, and I previously found no way to directly set it. As per the MS docs.

> ControlTemplate: this is used as the value of the Control.Template
>   property, which defines the visuals of a control by applying the
>   template. **You almost always define a ControlTemplate as a XAML
>   resource**, using an implicit key TargetType that is the same as a Style
>   that sets Control.Template with a Setter. You rarely if ever assign a
>   value for Control.Template directly on a control instance.

Besides possibly delving into reflection, or using the XAMLReader as per your first example, I have never found another way to do it, like you do in WPF.